# How to flatten Array[Reads[JsObject]] to Reads[JsObject] in scala

Tags: json, scala

```scala
import play.api.libs.json._

val trim:Array[String] = Array("k","p")
val js = Json.toJson(gmview) //gmview is a caseclass
val u: Array[Reads[JsObject]] =  trim map {
    case m=>  (__ \ "name").json.prune     //"name " is the field name
}
I want to do this, given below but I am getting error of 

> type mismatch; found : Array[play.api.libs.json.Reads[play.api.libs.json.JsObject]] required: play.api.libs.json.Reads[?]

val mdf = js.transform(u) match {
                            case data: JsSuccess[JsObject] => data.get
                            case e: JsError => {                               
                                null
                            }
                        }
```

I want the data type to be - `u: Reads[JsObject]`
How to do this? Thank you in advance for a help!

Comment: Hello! What is the Json library are you using, is this Play Json? And how resulting `Reads` should work - it should read the first element of an array? And could you provide also `trim` variable type. And please, prefer editing answer, rather then providing information in comment section. Thanks!

Comment: I have edited, have a look again